# May the prayer leader drink water (to lubricate his voice) during the weekday prayers?

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader, shacharis-morning-prayer, eating, water, chol-weekday

I have seen the person leading the prayers taking a drink of water (to lubricate his voice) during the weekday prayers.

Assuming he made a blessing (for the water, as usual before eating or drinking anything) before he started the prayers, is there any problem with doing this?

IMHO there seems to be a certain lack of respect to drink while addressing the Creator.

Are there any parts of the prayers where it is forbidden?

Comment: Potentially stupid random thought after reading the 3rd sentence of this question--Isn't it more disrespectful to the Creator to address Him while letting your voice strain, crack, or weaken or die out completely due to lack of throat lubrication?? Gargling saltwater might be pushing it, but a sip of water that avoids such a situation seems ok to me, IMHO.

Comment: @Gary Super thought.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

R. Yitzchak Abadi has told me that it's no problem, at any point in the prayers.

There is also no need to make a shehakol if one is drinking the water for the sole purpose of lubricating one's throat. Shehakol is only recited on water when the drinking serves the purpose of quenching one's thirst (see [Shulchan Aruch OC 204:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=219)).

Comment: Exact translation of חנקתיה אומצא? His throat is ...?

Comment: Something is stuck in his throat. Umtza is a raw piece of meat, something that was common to eat back then. So "the umtza is choking him." (Obviously this is a colloquial usage of the word choking; if someone were actually choking there is no doubt he is not obligated to recite a bracha before saving his life...)

Comment: What about if he also happens to be thirsty?

Comment: @Michoel well then he could make a Beracha anytime before Barechu and after Shemona Esreh.

Comment: @HachamGabriel - There's a validity limit on the shehacol though. And he would have to make the shehacol and drink (no hefsek allowed) _in case_ he might want to drink afterwards.