# Is Baal Kore allowed to drink water in the middle of reading Megillas Esther?

Tags: halacha, megillat-esther, eating, hefsek-interruption

If the reader drinks water to lubricate his vocal cords in the middle of a megilla reading, is it considered an interruption that would require him to re-start at the beginning or is there no need to restart?

Comment: slightly related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26343/may-the-prayer-leader-drink-water-to-lubricate-his-voice-during-the-weekday-pr

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much worse than "Pass the Groger"

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/18132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if one interrupts for any reason there is no need to start over, although preferably one should not interrupt the megillah. [see here](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.690.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)