Drinking during Leining
Is a Baal Koreh allowed to drink water during Leining to keep his voice smooth before hearing Kiddush?
The Shulchan Aruch does not allow one to drink even water before Kiddush. However, for a Choleh there are Heterim. I was wondering if this is a big enough tzorech?
Thank you

If it's not for thirst, is it even considered drinking?

Welcome to MiYodeya Benji and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

You can also bring a little bottle of grape juice and cookies and step out while they're singing אין כמוך

In theory, no water between shacharis amida and making kiddush; I've seen a lot of baalei kriah do it anyhow. However the Rambam is okay with water before kiddush, I wonder if that gets rolled into the heter somewhere.

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26343/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/143275
